# Limitar tamaño de texto y Evitar números con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy validando un `<input text>` y quiero que no se escriban más de 5 caracteres y que no acepten números, pero no obtengo resultados.

```js
$("#texto").on("keypress", function(event){           
    if(event.which > 47 || event.which < 58 || $(this).val().length == 5){
         return false;
     }                
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <input id="texto" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sin entrar en detalles de la comprobación que haces, sólo estás devolviendo `false`. Si no se entra en el condicional, no se devuelve un valor. Una función en JS que no retorna un valor usando `return`, devuelve siempre `undefined`, el cual es un valor [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Con esto, dado que tu función de validación se usa en un contexto booleano, siempre está devolviendo `false`. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Actualización**

El problema puede resolverse solo con html sin ayuda de jquery de la siguiente forma:

```html
<input id="texto" type="text" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" maxlength=5 >
```

Para evitar que se ingresen números se puede emplear el atributo `onkeypress`:

```
onkeypress="return !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)"
```

y para limitar el numero de máximo de caracteres que se puede ingresar al input se puede agregar:

```
maxlength=5
```

Para más información véase:

[**Bloquear números, letras y/o caracteres especiales en un input**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/289413/77879)

**Respuesta anterior**

El código esta bien, solo tienes un problema de lógica en esta parte:

```
if(event.which > 47 || event.which < 58 || $(this).val().length == 5){
```

Cuando colocas `event.which > 47 || event.which < 58` esto va a ser verdad siempre por tanto no se va a escribir ningún carácter. La forma correcta es:

```
 if((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58) || $(this).val().length == 5){
```

ya que lo que quieres es evitar los números entre **0 y 9**.

El código funcionando queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
    $("#texto").on("keypress", function(event){
        if((event.which > 47 && event.which < 58) || $(this).val().length == 5){
            return false;
        }
    });
```

```html
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="texto" type="text" size=5>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Hola, muy bien tu respuesta. Solo una observación. Se debe de ingresar una validación para que pueda borrar algun caracter por si se equivoca al ingresarlo. Quedando algo así: `if(event.which == 08){
        return true;
        }`

Comment: @LuisFernando, no creo que sea necesario, `(event.which > 47 && event.which < 58)` solo no permite que se ingresen números, luego todo lo demás esta permitido.

Comment: escribe 5 letras y trata de eliminar una, a ver que pasa, es que si tiene 5 letras no se puede borrar, solo es como observación para una posible mejora.

Comment: @LuisFernando, he probado en chrome y firefox y funciona correctamente, aunque entiendo que en teoría una vez llegado a los 5 caracteres debería rechazar cualquier cosa que se ingrese desde el teclado, en ese caso habría que pensar una alternativa a `$(this).val().length == 5` y que se valide de otra forma, de otro modo se llenaría de excepciones.

Comment: Exacto, a eso me refería.