# Bloquear números, letras y/o caracteres especiales en un input

Tags: html

Quisiera bloquear un `<input>` para que solo reciba números del 0-9 con un numero máximo de 10 dígitos, y que bloquee los caracteres especiales.

Solo quiero digital una cédula, sin caracteres especiales y tampoco letras.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="user">DOCUMENTO</label>
  <input type="text"  pattern="[0-9]" maxlength="10" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Solo caracteres Numericos"   class="form-control"
                  required autocomplete="off"/>
   <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

Luego, ¿que debería hacer si quiero recibir letras en lugar números, o si solo quiero bloquear caracteres especiales o si solo me interesa bloquear un carácter en particular?

Comment: Tienes alguna limitancia que no ocupas js? Esta logica sería facil de programar con un dom script con javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer agregando esta linea a tu input:

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)"
```

Código funcionando:

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Solo caracteres Numericos"   class="form-control"
              required autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" min="1" />
```

**Explicación:**

`onkeypress=""` toma el evento cuando el usuario presiona una tecla (del teclado).

`event.charCode` captura el código ascii de la tecla presionada.

Para definir los intervalos se pueden usar los operadores `!` (not lógico), `&&` (and lógico) y `||` (or lógico) y agrupar con parentesis.

Puedes ver una lista completa de las teclas y sus códigos asociados en este enlace por ejemplo:

**[El código ASCII Completo](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)**

En base a esa información se puede establecer el intervalo de caracteres que serán aceptados en el input.

Para números [0-9]: 48-57

Para letras (mayúsculas y minúsculas) sin números [a-zA-Z]: 65-90, 97-122

Para letras (solo minúsculas) sin números [a-z]: 97-122

Para letras (solo mayúsculas) sin números [A-Z]: 65-90

Para números y letras [0-9a-zA-Z]: 48-57,65-90,97-122

Ejemplo con letras sin números:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Solo caracteres alfabeticos" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122))"  />
```

Ejemplo con letras y números:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Sin caracteres especiales"  onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122))"  />
```

Para bloquear y/o permitir algún carácter especial antes se debe buscar el código de tecla, he aquí una tabla con algunos carateres y sus códigos:

```
carácter             |código
----------------------------
espacio en blanco ( )|32
comilla simple (')   |39
comillas dobles (")  |34
barra diagonal (/)   |47
barra diagonal (\)   |92
arroba (@)           |64
letra Ñ              |209
letra ñ              |241
```

Para agregar dicho carácter al intervalo se puede emplear `event.charCode == [codigo]` o para omitirlo `event.charCode != [código]`.

Ejemplo permitir todos los caracteres excepto comillas simples:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Sin comillas simples"  onkeypress="return event.charCode != 39"  />
```

Ejemplo permitir solo letras incluyendo Ñ y ñ:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Incluye Ñ y ñ"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 209 || event.charCode == 241 || (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122))"  />
```

Si buscas algún carácter y desconoces el código, ingresalo en el siguiente input para obtenerlo:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa un caracter"  onkeypress="console.log(event.charCode)"  />
```

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias ha sido muy útil, me podrías pasar algún tipo de documento explicando el funcionamiento, es que quisiera bloquear todos los caracteres especiales en otros tipos de inputs.

Comment: @Yero como no con mucho gusto, puedo pasarte una breve explicación del código y que hacer para incluir/bloquear otros caracteres.

Comment: Te agradecería , quisiera bloquear solo caracteres especiales, pero no bloquear letras,para datos como nombres y apellidos.O tal vez habra otra forma mas corta para bloquear caracteres especiales.