# Restringir caracteres en input

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente inconveniente necesito restringir ciertos  caracteres en un input y no encuentro la forma he probado con pattern pero no me funciona . Los caracteres que debo restringir son todos menos números enteros, el guión medio "-" y letras solo mayúsculas. Tal vez en javascript Muchas gracias

```
<html>
 <div class="col-md-4 ">
             <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
             <input type="text" maxlength="16" pattern="[A-Za-z]{4-16}" class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" placeholder="Expediente" required >
           </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, puede servirte revisar [Bloquear números, letras y/o caracteres especiales en un input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289413/bloquear-n%c3%bameros-letras-y-o-caracteres-especiales-en-un-input/289418#289418)

Comment: Gracias. si es un buen ejemplo ahora estoy probando con KeyCodes javascript para restringir con el evento onkeypress..

Comment: Gracias, encontré la solución en el link de la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible forma es capturando el evento `input` del `<input>` y cambiarle el valor cada vez que ingrese algo. Podemos usar una regex del estilo `[^A-Z\d-]` en la que definimos lo que dejamos pasar, ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("expediente").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = value.replace(/[^A-Z\d-]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<html>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="16" class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" placeholder="Expediente" required>
</div>

</html>
```

De un modo similar, puedes forzar un formato específico, como por ejémplo incluír los guiones donde quieras que esten.

Comment: Muchas gracias ...sus respuestas ayudaron mucho!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero muchas gracias , sus respuestas me ayudaron  y lo resolvi de la siguiente manera, espero les sirva a otros en el input lo deje de la siguiente manera

```
<html>
<div class="col-md-4 ">
  <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="16" class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" onkeypress="return alpha(event)" placeholder="Expediente" required>
</div>

</html>
```

// funcion javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function alpha(e) { var k; document.all ? k = e.key : k = e.which; return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 45 || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57)); }


</script>
```