# Bloquear secuencia de números de un input

Tags: html, input

estoy intentando hacer que en un input no se pueda usar el 1234 pero si el 1423... no se si se entiende.. que la secuencia "1234" no se permita pero si se usan esos caracteres "desordenadamente" si lo permita. Se puede hacer? Seria como bloquear una cierta secuencia de números.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Que has intentado? Deberías de adjunta el código que llevas.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida debes proveer un [mcve], de esa forma será más fácil ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Hola gabriel, gracias por responder la verdad que no he intentado nada ya que no se me ocurre nada de como hacerlo.

Comment: Que tal Nicolas, eso lo puedes lograr solo con javascript, quiza esto responda a tu pregunta  (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/289413/bloquear-n%C3%BAmeros-letras-y-o-caracteres-especiales-en-un-input), te recomiendo edites tu pregunta con algo que hayas intentado, normalmente este tipo de preguntas terminan cerradas

Comment: Hola saúl, pasa que no intente nada solo he buscado por todos lados para lograr lo que quiero pero no encuentro nada y tampoco se me ocurre como hacerlo. El link que me has pasado lo he visto antes pero no es lo que quiero. Yo quiero bloquear una secuencia específica de números pero no caracteres en particular.. por ejemplo quiero bloquear el 3323 pero no el 3 y el 2... la verdad es que no se si me hago entendes bien. Lo siento